# Fetch more content as user is scrolling down

Tags: reactjs

I have a page with a search input, once the user click on submit results come up.

There can be a lot of results and I don't want to load them all at once, how can I fetch more data into the page using Lodash throttle on mouse move?

This is my react component:

```
const getContacts = async (searchString) => {
  const { data: contactsInfo} = await axios.get(`api/Contats/Search?contactNum=${searchString}`);
  return contactsInfo;
};
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    contactsInfo: [],
    searchString: '',
  };

  handleSubmit = async () => {
    const { searchString } = this.state;
    const contactsInfo = await getContacts(searchString);
    this.setState({ contactsInfo });
  };

  onInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      searchString: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  onMouseMove = e => {

  };

  render() {
    const { contactsInfo, searchString, } = this.state;
    return (
          <div css={bodyWrap} onMouseMove={e => this.onMouseMove(e)}>
            <Header appName="VERIFY" user={user} />
            {user.viewApp && (
              <div css={innerWrap}>
                <SearchInput
                  searchIcon
                  value={searchString || ''}
                  onChange={e => this.onInputChange(e)}
                  handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                />
                     {contactsInfo.map(info => (
                      <SearchResultPanel
                        info={info}
                        isAdmin={user.isAdmin}
                        key={info.id}
                      />
                    ))}
              </div>
            )}
            <Footer />
          </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I supposed that, using `getContacts()` you retrieve ALL the contacts, and then you just want to show them at some rate, like showing the first 20, then when you reach the last one, another 20s appear.
Just asking because this is really different from "let's fetch the first 20 contacts, show them, and when the user reaches the last one, fetch another 20s".

So, if the first assumption I've made it's correct, I can raccomend you to use the **Intersection Observer API** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

This is really useful in case like yours (it's even written in the documentation *"Lazy-loading of images or other content as a page is scrolled."*).

The idea is that you should add this Intersection Observer, and start the observation on the last image: this observator will run a callback as soon as the last image appears on the screen (you can even decide the percentage of the image that must be on the screen).
For example, you can say that, as soon as 1px of the image appear on the screen, you add another 20s images!

Notice that, once another 20s images are shown, you must unobserve the currect observed image, and observe the new last image!

I can also suggest to not put the observer on the last image, but maybe on the third last.

**EDIT:** I'm not sure this answers your question. It does if I consider the title "Fetch more content as user is scrolling down", but it does not actually use mouseover (even though I think this implementation is the best one for your goal).

**EDIT2:** There it goes, I've added the fiddle, and here there is the codepen: https://codepen.io/Gesma94/pen/OqpOQb

Note that I've simulated the contacts with divs of different color. What is going on is that, when the third last contact (div) appear on the screen, new contacts are added in the state. Right now the contacts are just empty objects, but you can run a fetch or doing whatever you want inside `fetchMoreContent()`. Is this clear enough? :) I've commented the code too.

```js
/* Just a function that create a random hex color. */
function randomColor() {
    let randomColor = '#';
    const letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';

    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        randomColor += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];   
    }
    
    return randomColor;
}

class Home extends React.Component {
    contactList = null; // Ref to the div containing the contacts.
    contactObserved = null; // The contact which is observed.
    intersectionObserver = null; // The intersectionObserver object.
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.contactList = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            contactsToShow: 0,
            contacts: []
        };
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        /* Perform fetch here. I'm faking a fetch using setTimeout(). */
        setTimeout(() => {
            const contacts = [];
            for (let i=0; i<100; i++) contacts.push({});
            
            this.setState({loading: false, contacts, contactsToShow: 10})}, 1500);
    }
    
    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (!this.state.loading) this.handleMoreContent();
    }
    
    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <p>Loading..</p>
        }
        
        return (
            <div ref={this.contactList}>
                {this.state.contacts.map((contact, index) => {
                    if (index < this.state.contactsToShow) {
                        const color = contact.color || randomColor();
                        contact.color = color;                    

                        return (
                            <div
                                className="contact"
                                style={{background: color}}>
                                {color}
                            </div>
                        );
                    }
                    
                })}
            </div>
            
        );
    }

    handleMoreContent = () => {
        /* The third last contact is retrieved. */
        const contactsDOM = this.contactList.current.getElementsByClassName("contact");
        const thirdLastContact = contactsDOM[contactsDOM.length - 3];

        /* If the current third last contact is different from the current observed one,
         *  then the observation target must change. */
        if (thirdLastContact !== this.contactObserved) {
            /* In case there was a contact observed, we unobserve it and we disconnect the
             *  intersection observer. */
            if (this.intersectionObserver && this.contactObserved) {
                this.intersectionObserver.unobserve(this.contactObserved);
                this.intersectionObserver.disconnect();
            }
            
            /* We create a new intersection observer and we start observating the new third
             *  last contact. */
            this.intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(this.loadMoreContent, {
                root: null,
                threshold: 0
            });
        
            this.intersectionObserver.observe(thirdLastContact);
            this.contactObserved = thirdLastContact;
        }
    }
    
    loadMoreContent = (entries) => {
         entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                let contactsCounter = this.state.contacts.length;
                let contactsToShow = this.state.contactsToShow + 10;
        
                if (contactsToShow > contactsToShow) contactsToShow = contactsToShow;
        
                this.setState({contactsToShow});
            }
        })
        
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.contact {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.contact + .contact {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm not sure what makes the most sense, I think fetching more data from the API would make more sense rather than getting all `contacts` once.

Comment: Well, I think it mostly depends on how many contacts there would be, at most. And how "big" is a contact, in terms of bytes.
If it was me, I would fetch all the contacts at once if they are 100-200 or less.. Then you may also consider "how frequently could happen that the user will scroll and require other contacts?"..
Anyway, in both cases, using the Intersection Observer is THE solution: instead of just displaying new images, the callback will run a new fetch API, and retrieve new contacts. You can also add a loading spin effect using the Promise of that fetch :)

Comment: Well.. Honestly, it's up to you. At this point, if you say that they can reach thousands (300? 400? ..), I would go with different fetches. It wouldn't be more difficult, you just need to call a fetch in the IntersectionObserver callback and update the state, in which I guess you are saving the contacts.
Do you need a fiddle for that? Or do you need help with an example?

Comment: Usually it won't be more than a few results but if they search for example by one letter there can be thousands of results... In such a case the page crashes that's why I want to add some logic to now show all the results at once. If you can give me an example it would be very helpful, thank you!

Comment: I will write an example on CodePen as soon as possible and will edit my answer

Comment: Example added :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the example, where should I initially get all `contacts` from the api?

Comment: I guess in `ComponentDidMount` you should run the first query, and then in `fetchMoreContent` the future ones. Notice that, if you want to retrieve contacts with different fetches, I think you need the Pagination on rest API (not really familiar with that but I know it's used for what would achieve)

Comment: Is there a way to get the `contacts` all at once and fetch them on the pgae part by part with `intersectionObserver`?

Comment: You call the fetch in the `componentDidMount` method, and in its callback you save all the contacts in the state and a property `contactsToShow`, which is the number of the contacts you want to display. Then, inside the callback on the `intersectionObserver` you just increase `contactsToShow`.
I've updated the codepen and the example in the answer.